# How to mutate all queries of a model in only one location in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a app where each user has your own customer. These customers can store tickets, and the users can see only the tickets that belogns to his customer.

Can I "intercept" all the queries with this where clause? I dont want put this logic everytime that I need to do a query.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent and building the relationships?

Comment: Yes. But in this case all that a I need is this: 
$query->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customer_id). In all ticket's queries.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use global scopes?

Comment: I was not aware of it. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user3158900's help. I found this: [Query Scopes - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)